# Connecting Windows 7 to a Snow Leopard 10.6.5 shared folder

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, connection-sharing, shared-folders

I'm trying to connect from a **Windows 7** computer to a **Snow Leopard 10.6.5** without find a way to do it. I easily access to my shared folders in **Windows** from **Snow Leopard** but I can't do viceversa.

In **Snow Leopard 10.6.5**, from **System Preferences > File Sharing**, I've added a folder to share, activated **SMB** for **Windows** and I've configured my workgroup in **System Preferences > Network > Ethernet > WINS** but I still **can't connect from Windows to Leopard**.

With **SoftPerfect Network Scanner** in Windows I can see the IP of my Leopard machine but without shared folders active. I've also restarted my MAC but it won't work.

How can I solve it? Does exist some guide to fix it?

Windows return **0x80004005** error code.

To be more clear, I have a **XAMPP** server installed on my **Snow Leopard** machine and I'd like to test the sites I make on my Windows client and edit them if needed directly from some Windows text editor to be more faster. I don't know if this could be a **XAMPP** problem, because I'm forced to enable the **root user** to manage it, but Windows can't also see the other shared folders which aren't managed with the root user.

I can edit my files via **FTP** from Windows to Snow Leopard web server but still, I can't see OSX shared folders, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Can you ping your mac from your PC? Type `ping ip.of.mac.computer` into your PC's command prompt, and see if there is any response.

Comment: yes it works, if I ping Snow Leopard, Windows see it fastly. It seems a missing configuration in Snow Leopard but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you access it through \\servername\sharename in explorer window?